# Singleton service in Angular (w/ Ionic)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dependency-injection

I'm having some issues trying to make a singleton service to provide state across my application: in some cases, when a page is created, the service gets a new instance, but only in some pages. To navigate between pages I'm using NavController's method `navigateRoot()`, don't know if this can help.

Here is the service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateService implements OnDestroy {
  count: number;

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    console.log('Service created');
  }

  setState() {
    this.count++;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { // Never gets called
    console.log('Service closed'); 
  }
}
```

A component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'a-page',
  templateUrl: './a.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.page.scss'],
})
export class APage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    ...
    private state: StateService
  ) {
    this.state.setState();
    ...
  };

}
```

I've also tried the method where I add the service to the `app.component.ts` providers, but that didn't work either.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: on destroy should implemented on page and not on service, service can't be desteoyed except if u rest its variables by urself using a function and clear ur variables in this function to their default state, now i didn't know the scenario u need to achieve but this summary is for ngOnDestroy part. Now u need to clarify or give a simple scenarii for what you want to achieve so i can help u achieve it..

Comment: @MostafaHarb the ngOnDestroy was just to see if the service was being destroyed before a new one was created (my bad). What I'm trying to achieve is to have a way to have state (and more specificaly state machines, with xstate) across the app. I've turned the problem broader because i thought that it wouldn't make a diference. Explaining you the flow, in terms of pages: Splash -> Pin -> Menu -> Info -> Menu. On every page the constructor of the StateService is called, except the second time on Menu page. I can't see what can cause this behavior

Comment: Add ur code inside ionViewWillEnter() and not in constructor, since constructor is being initiated on page open and will not be called again except after page be completly destroyed, so ionViewWillEnter will be called anytime the page is accessed..

Comment: @MostafaHarb sorry but I'm not understanding how that could resolve my problem. I want to have just one instance of StateService across my app. The problem right now is that "Service created" is being logged on every view, losing all the state each time a new view is loaded

Comment: Ok then remove this.count = 0  in constructor, and add = 0 directly to the declaration, count:number = 0, and the state will not be reset to zero on each time u access the service, since each time u call any function the constructor will be also activated and it is making the count to be zero each time ..

Comment: @MostafaHarb that didn't work either. If I call ```setState()``` on each page ```ngOnInit()```, following the same flow, I should get count=3 on Menu, but I get =2. The value of count is on each page: Splash=1, Pin=1 (new state instance), Menu=2

Comment: I narrowed the problem to the Splash page, but I still can't identify it. Comparing to the other components, there is nothing outside the normal.

Comment: @MostafaHarb thank you for your time! I managed to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the import of the service in a specific page had the `.js` extension which made it malfunction across the application (linter was deactivated, two days lost :( )